# Why did we allocate memory for matrix with double pointers?

Tags: c, data-structures

I have a hard time understanding this code:

```
int **arr = malloc(l * sizeof(int *));
for (i=0; i<l; i++)
  ​arr[i] = (int *)malloc(c * sizeof(int));`
```

1. Why did we use a double pointer and not just one?
2. And also I didn't understand the logic behind this code, so can you please explain it to me line by line.

Comment: Q1 seems like a question for yourself. Why did you write this code?

Comment: Say you have a single pointer: `int *p;`  What can it point to?  It points to an int that might have other ints next to it (so, either a single int or a 1D array of int)  So if you want a 2D array of int you need a pointer that points to a 1D array - and that's what `int **p;`is: a pointer to an array of integer pointers that can each point to a 1D array of ints.

Comment: @JerryJeremiah What a good and simple explanation, thank you

Comment: @M.M Now i get what you were saying . thanks

Comment: @JerryJeremiah if you want 2D array you wont get it with double pointer. Array is a continuous chunk of memory. Memory allocated the way shown in the question does not meet this requirement. It is a very common misunderstanding.

Comment: A "double pointer" is declared `double *`.  A variable declared `int **` is a "pointer to pointer to int".

Comment: @0___________ Fair enough.  Let me rephrase: Say you have a single pointer: int *p; What can it point to? It points to an int that might have other ints next to it (so, either a single int or a 1D array of int) So if you want an array of int that can be indexed in a similar way to a 2D array then you need a pointer that points to a 1D array - and that's what int **p;is: a pointer to an array of integer pointers that can each point to a 1D array of ints.

Comment: @WilliamPursell no, it is not. `double *` is a **pointer to double** not *double pointer*.

Comment: @JerryJeremiah no it is only pointer to pointer to integer not pointer to the integer array which in C language is very well defined and has its own specific syntax and distinctly differ if you for example consider the pointer arithmetic.

Answer (score 1):

The posted code allocates an indirect 2D matrix: an array of pointers each pointing to an array of `int`. This is allows for the matrix cells to be referred to as `array2D[i][j]` and was the solution in classic C (pre-c99) for variable numbers of columns.

C99 allows for a more efficient way to allocate or manipulate matrices with variable numbers of columns using a new construction called variable length arrays (VLA). This feature is not available in C++, that has more specific ways to represent vectors and matrices. It was not implemented in all C compilers and the Standard Committee decided to make it optional as of C11.

Here is an example using VLAs:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void matrix_init(int rows, int cols, int matrix[rows][cols]) {
    int n = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
            matrix[i][j] = n++;
        }
    }
}

void matrix_print(int rows, int cols, int matrix[rows][cols]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
            printf("  %d", matrix[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

int main() {
    int rows = 3;
    int cols = 4;
    // define `matrix` as a pointer to arrays of `cols` integers.
    // allocate the matrix as an array of such variable length arrays.
    // could also write `calloc(sizeof(int[cols]), rows)` 
    int (*matrix)[cols] = calloc(sizeof(*matrix), rows);
    matrix_init(rows, cols, matrix);
    matrix_print(rows, cols, matrix);
    free(matrix);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Why did we use a double pointer and not just one?

Double pointers are used to let syntax `x[i][j]` work.
Simply speaking `[]` involves dereference and removing one star (`*`) from variable's type.

For example:

```
int *p;  // p type is int*
p[3];    // p[3] type is int
int **q; // q type is int**
q[2];    // q[2] type is int*
q[2][3]; // q[2][3] type is int
```

Answer (score -1):

there is a distinct difference between the pointer to int and the pointer to int array. Below you have an example how to allocate the memory for the 2D array.

```
    int (*array2D)[rows][cols] = malloc(sizeof(*array2D));
```

Comment: This doesn't answer either of the questions the OP asked.  He wasn't asking how to get a pointer to contiguous memory that could be used as a 2D array - he was asking how the code he put in the question worked.

Comment: And the whole "we" in quotes thing is condescending.  Would you have prefered this "Why does one ...?" which is arguably better grammar?

Comment: @JerryJeremiah he asked how the double-pointer is used to allocate the 2D array, showing the code which does not allocate the 2D array. It is a very common misunderstanding

Comment: He doesn't use the phrase "2D array" anywhere in his question.  He asked why a "double pointer" was necessary in the code he showed.  And your answer doesn't explain that.

Comment: He uses word matrix

Comment: A matrix can be any kind of data structure that can be indexed with two numbers.  You could make a linked list that acred as a matrix (a sparse matrix is often allocated this way)

Comment: OK, since let's end this discussion and clean up the comments.